# Reverse for 'Page' not found. 'Page' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

this is the error I got when I wanted to create a dynamic sitemap.

sitemap.py

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
#models
from home.models import Page


class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):

priority = 0.5
changefreq = "daily"
protocol = 'https'

def items(self):
    return [
        'home:about',           
        ]

def location(self, item):
    return reverse(item)

def lastmod(self, item):
    return timezone.now()


class DynamicSitemap(Sitemap):
 changefreq = "daily"
 priority = 0.5

 def items(self):
    return Page.objects.all()
```

models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
city =  models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Şehir")
seo     = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Seo")

def __str__(self):
    return self.city

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('home:page', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

home/urls.py:

```
app_name = "home"

urlpatterns = [
 # ⋮,
 path(r'page/<int:pk>', views.yardimsayfalari, name="page"),
 # ⋮,
]
```

static sitemap works fine but dynamic sitemap I get the same error. Thank you to those who are interested so far.

I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you show the `urls.py` where you defined the `Page` view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, my English is bad and I didn't understand you clearly. Do you want me to share the urls.py page?

Comment: @ymlusoft: yes, the one where the `get_absolute_url` is referring to in your `Page` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Umm sana istediğini verebildim

Comment: no what is missing is the URL patterns where your `'Page'` is referring to. Likely these are the `home/urls.py`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I guess I could give the right answer :)

Comment: can you provide the *full* traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `get_absolute_url`, you try to link this to:

```
path(r'page', views.yardimsayfalari, name='page'),
```

The name of your view is `page`, not <s>`Page`</s>. Furthermore you specified `app_name = 'home'`, hence full name of the view is `home:page`. Finally your path does *not* contain any parameter, so `args=(self.pk,)` makes not much sense.

You thus likely should include a primary key parameter:

```
app_name = "home"

urlpatterns = [
    # ⋮,
    path('page/<int:pk>/', views.yardimsayfalari, name="page"),
    # ⋮,
]
```

include that `pk` parameter in your view:

```
def yardimsayfalari(request, pk):
    # …
    # return HTTP response
```

and finally refer to the view with:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    # ⋮

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home:page', args=(self.pk,))
```

It might also make more sense to work with a named parameter, so:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    # ⋮

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home:page', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

based on this, I would advise to (re)read the [third part of the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/).

Comment: The problem is related to another issue. :)

Comment: @yumlusoft: without a traceback, it is hard to know what the issue is...